# How do I create RAW TCP/IP packets in C++?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm a beginning C++ programmer / network admin, but I figure I can learn how to do this if someone points me in the right direction. Most of the tutorials are demonstrated using old code that no longer works for some reason.

Since I'm on Linux, all I need is an explanation on how to write raw Berkeley sockets. Can someone give me a quick run down?

Comment: [Beej's network guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) is pretty much the gold standard of anything related to basic networking in a linux environment. It is simple and to the point, I can't recommend it more highly.

Comment: RAW sockets are very tricky and are a bit different on different systems. I'm only aware of folks using them to code sniffers (like `wireshark`) and some rather arcane diagnostics. They're certainly not a good place to start learning socket programming. In most cases "I'm a beginning C++ programmer / network admin" means "stay away from SOCK_RAW".

Comment: @ChuckKollars, I disagree. I think learning raw sockets is a great way of learning C++, and especially C. Using a library is one thing, but raw sockets with Linux is a very insightful experience. C++ can do so many unique things. I think avoiding the heartache you imply is a mistake.

Comment: What system exactly do you have? "Raw" socket implementations differ considerably from one system to the next, so that what you learn (really mostly about the system, not about C++) doesn't carry over elsewhere.

Comment: @ChuckKollars, That is true; I was referring more to the multitudinous uses of structures, and less to portability of code.

Comment: Wireshark and tcpdump both use libpcap to capture network traffic; libpcap, on Linux, uses `PF_PACKET` sockets, which might be `SOCK_RAW` or `SOCK_DGRAM` (the choice depends on the device on which you're capturing).  Neither of them use, for example, `PF_INET` or `PF_INET6` `SOCK_RAW` packets; those are for sending raw IPv4 or IPv6 packets.

Answer (score 14):

Start by reading [Beej's guide on socket programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) . It will bring you up to speed on how to start writing network code. After that you should be able to pick up more and more information from reading the man pages.

Most of it will consist of reading the documentation for your favourite library, and a basic understanding of man pages.

Comment: The link you provided above is not working anymore. Here is the new one https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/

Answer (score 11):

For starters, it would be helpful if you clarify what you mean by "raw".  Traditionally this means that you want to craft all of the layer 4 header (TCP/UDP/ICMP... header), and perhaps some of the IP header on your own.  For this you will need more than beej's tutorial which has been mentioned my many here already.  In this case you want raw IP sockets obtained using the SOCK_RAW argument in your call to socket (see http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html for some basics).

If what you really want is just to be able to establish a TCP connection to some remote host such as port 80 on stackoverflow.com, then you probably don't need "raw" sockets and beej's guide will serve you well.

For an authoritative reference on the subject, you should really pick up Unix Network Programming, Volume 1: The Sockets Networking API (3rd Edition) by Stevens et al.

Answer (score 5):

**For TCP client side:**

Use gethostbyname to lookup dns name to IP, it will return a hostent structure.  Let's call this returned value host.

```
hostent *host = gethostbyname(HOSTNAME_CSTR);
```

Fill the socket address structure:

```
sockaddr_in sock;
sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
sock.sin_port = htons(REMOTE_PORT);
sock.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->s_addr;
```

Create a socket and call connect:

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sock, sizeof(sock))
```

**For TCP server side:**

Setup a socket

Bind your address to that socket using bind.

Start listening on that socket with listen

Call accept to get a connected client.  <-- at this point you spawn a new thread to handle the connection while you make another call to accept to get the next connected client.

**General communication:**

Use send and recv to read and write between the client and server.

**Source code example of BSD sockets:**

You can find some good example code of this at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).

**Further reading:**

I highly recommend [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) and [this online tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html):

[image]

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIP1b.jpg):

Comment: gethostbyname should no longer be used for a new project: it is tied to an IP version (IPv4). Now that the remaining stock of IPv4 addresses is [rapidly depleting](http://www.potaroo.net/tools/ipv4/index.html), you really should use getaddrinfo which is version-independent (works with v4 and v6).

Answer (score 4):

A good place to start would be to use [Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html) which is a great cross-platform (incl Linux) library for network communication.

Comment: You can never make a UDP packet look or behave like a TCP packet - the IP packet headers for the two are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

You do this the exact same way you would in regular C, there is no C++ specific way to do this in the standard library.

The tutorial I used for learning this was http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/. It was the best tutorial I found after looking around, it gave clear examples and good explanations of all functions it describes.

Answer (score 3):

I've been developing [libtins](http://libtins.github.io/) for the past year. It's a high level C++ packet crafting and sniffing library.

Unless you want to reinvent the wheel and implement every protocol's internals, I'd recommend you to use some higher level library which already does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of references on this (of course, Stevens' book comes to mind), but I found the [Beej guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) to be incredibly useful for getting started.  It's meaty enough that you can understand what's really happening, but it's simple enough that it doesn't take you several days to write a 'hello world' udp client/server.

Answer (score 1):

easy:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int socket(int protocolFamily, int Type, int Protocol)
// returns a socket descriptor

int bind(int socketDescriptor, struct sockaddr* localAddress, unsigned int addressLength)
// returns 0
```

...etc.

it's all in sys/socket.h

Answer (score 1):

Poster, please clarify your question.

Almost all responses seem to think you're asking for a sockets tutorial; I read your question to mean you need to create a raw socket capable of sending arbitrary IP packets.
As I said in my previous answer, some OSes restrict the use of raw sockets.

http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw
"Only processes with an effective user ID of 0 or the CAP_NET_RAW capability are allowed to open raw sockets."

Answer (score 1):

Read [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) by Richard Stevens.  It's a must.  It explains how it all works, gives you code, and even gives you helper methods.  You might want to check out some of his other books.  [Advanced Programming In The Unix Enviernment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079) is a must for lower level programming in Unix is general.  I don't even do stuff on the Unix stack anymore, and the stuf from these books still helps how I code.

Answer (score 1):

[Libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) will let you craft complete packets (layer2 through layer 7) and send them out over the wire.  As fun as that sounds, there's some caveats with it.  You need to create all the appropriate headers and do all the checksumming yourself.  [Libnet](http://libnet.sourceforge.net/) can help with that, though.

If you want to get out of the C++ programming pool, there is [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) for python.  It makes it trivial to craft and transmit TCP/IP packets.

Answer (score 1):

in any case, if you want to use the tcp/ip stack, their headers will be added to your packet. If you want to control the packet down to the byte, I advise you npcap. Libpcap, unfortunately, is already outdated, although it is much easier to use. However, I have personally used npcap and it provides full control over the package

Comment: They said they're "on Linux", which means neither WinPcap nor Npcap are available, as they're Windows-only - instead, libpcap is available, but uses Linux's `PF_PACKET` sockets.  On Linux and other UN\*Xes, libpcap uses the OS's built-in capture mechanism; Windows doesn't offer one, so both WinPcap and Npcap combine libpcap with a kernel driver and library to communicate with that driver.  *WinPcap* is outdated; *libpcap* isn't - it's the part of Npcap that programmers usually use.

Comment: as far as I know wireshark works exactly on npcap and I often work on it on both windows and linux, so I assumed that npcap is available on linux. For Windows, this is really almost the only way.

Comment: Wireshark uses the libpcap API to do packet capture.  On UN*Xes, it uses the libpcap that comes with the OS.  On Windows, it uses either WinPcap's libpcap DLL or Npcap's libpcap DLL (both loaded at run time, so that the Wireshark binary can run with or without WinPcap/Npcap installed; without WinPcap/Npcap, it supports reading capture files but not performing live captures).